# Use the same rails form for AJAX and non AJAX calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a simple_form for a Model. The form for the new action si basic, like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @patient do |f| %>
    .... fields
<% end %>
```

I want to use this form in the `New` view, but also in a bootstrap modal with AJAX. If I use this syntax:

```
<%= render partial: 'patients/form', locals: {patient: @patient, remote: true} %>
```

But when I do this I only can access the local variable with remote, not @remote, which will render an error in the `new` view.

EDIT

The call for the partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'patients/form', locals: {patient: @patient, remote: true } %>
```

And the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @patient, remote: @remote do |f| %>
    .... fields
<% end %>
```

Any way to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why does that cause an error?  What error do you get?

Comment: In the view, if I use @remote variable to set the form `remote: @remote` has no value, and if i use `remote: remote` I get an error in the New view

Comment: Just call it a different name.... `remote_toggle: true` then call `data: { remote: remote_toggle }` in your partial

Comment: Is that because you're not passing remote from new and remote local variable is undefined?

Comment: looks like that. I will try in  a sec.

Comment: The local variable passed to the partial is `remote`, not `@remote`, so I will have 2 variables for the remote switch, one `@remote` when comming from the new action and one `remote` from the render partial call.

Comment: Can you post the code for the link which calls the modal?

Comment: No. I asked the link which triggers the modal

Comment: `<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddPatient">Add new patient</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can send the `request` to the modal as `Ajax` and in the `form` use `remote: request.xhr?` So that you can use the form for both Ajax and Non-Ajax calls.</strike>

`<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"  data-remote="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddPatient">Add new patient</a>`

And in the form

```
#form

<%= simple_form_for @patient, remote: request.xhr? do |f| %>
    .... fields
<% end %>
```

`request.xhr?` returns `true` if the `request` is an `Ajax request` else it returns `false`. So it will be `remote: true` for Ajax call and `remote: false` for non-Ajax call.

***Update:***

Ok. Somehow the above approach didn't worked for you. Try the below approach

Define a local variable while calling a partial

```
<%= render partial: 'patients/form', locals: {patient: @patient, modal: true} %>
```

And in the form

```
<% modal ||= false %>
<% remote = modal ? true : false %>
<%= simple_form_for @patient, remote: remote do |f| %>
    .... fields
<% end %>
```

Comment: It is not working. On the form the `request.xhr?` is empty.

Comment: @HMihail Did you chaned the link as mine?

Comment: Yes, I put the data-remote in the link.

Comment: @HMihail Can you post the log generated when you click the link?

Comment: It says: `Started GET "/appointments/new?clinic_id=2&physician_id=17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-18 13:39:28 +0200
Processing by AppointmentsController#new as JS`

Comment: @HMihail Try changing `<%= render partial: 'patients/form', locals: {patient: @patient, remote: true} %>` to `<%= render partial: 'patients/form', locals: {patient: @patient} %>`

Comment: Same result. request.xhr? still empty.